# Umgangssprachlich eigene Meinung äußern

Tags: vocabulary, informal

Wie kann man umgangssprachlich seine eigene Meinung äußern? Ich interessiere mich nur für die Phrasen, bzw. Wörter, die in der Alltagsprache tatsächlich verwendet werden.

Mir fallen nur die Folgenden ein:

> Ich finde [etwas] + [Adj]_
>   Das halte ich für [Adj/Subst]_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vieles wurde ja schon genannt.

Ich ergänze um:

- Ich glaube....
- Ich denke, dass...
- Das ist doch...
- Ich sage doch schon immer, dass...

Ich hatte in der Zeit nach der Wende (ist ja schon ein bißchen her...) die interessante Erfahrung, dass plötzlich neue Formen dazu kamen, die alle den Konjunktiv gebrauchten:

- Ich würde meinen, dass...
- Ich würde mal sagen, dass...
- Ich *möchte* meinen, dass...
- Ich würde sagen, dass...

Für Letzteren gibt mir Google ngrams auch eine Bestätigung. Einen Versuch der Erklärung *würde ich mir jetzt einmal sparen wollen*...

Auch ein netter Ausdruck ist eine Phrase meines Lehrmeisters (vor 30 Jahren...), der immer sagte

- Meine Rede seit '33, dass...

Der zielte extrem auf die "Persilschein-Aspiranten" der 50-er und 60-er Jahre - Das heisst, Leute, die am Ende der Nazi-Zeit mit großen Tönen verbreitet haben, dass sie ja schon immer gewußt hätten, "dass das nicht gut ausgehen kann" und deswegen von Anfang an "dagegen" gewesen wären.

Comment: Das mit den Aspiranten ist ungestützt besonders für Lernende schwer zu verstehen.

Comment: Das stimmt - bei einer Frage nach umgangssprachlichen Ausdrücken dachte ich, ich kann mir das erlauben...

Comment: Heh, Danke für die Zustimmung. Ich hatte mir erhofft, dass Du eine entsprechende Erklärung dazubaust :D

Comment: Nicht vom Handy - Aber jetzt ;)

Answer (score 8):

- *Meines Erachtens [ist diese Frage berechtigt.]* (gehobene Ausdrucksweise)
- *Meiner Meinung nach [ist heute Ostermontag.]*
- *Meiner Ansicht nach [ist Frank Plasberg das, was sich das Ausland unter einem Deutschen vorstellt.]*
- *Meiner Überzeugung nach [sind die Würfel längst gefallen: Russland wird immer größer.]*
- *Meiner Auffassung nach [zählt man Nachbarn nicht zu den Menschen.]*
- *Mein Standpunkt [ist ein anderer: Lass es sein.]*
- *Meinem Gefühl nach [ist der Wind der natürliche Feind der Frisur.]*
- *Für **mein** Empfinden [wäre das Nichts natürlich; die Tatsache, dass
  etwas existiert, ist eine Sensation.]* (gehobene Ausdrucksweise)
- *Meinem Eindruck nach [ziehen jetzt schon wieder 800 Melchiore,
  Kaspare und Balthasare durch die Stadt.]*
- *Das [er]scheint mir [richtig.]*
- *Eins sag ich dir: [Um den Bürger geht es schon lange nicht mehr.]*
- *[Das] sehe ich anders: [Deine Fröhlichkeit ist angesoffen.]*
- *Nach meinem Dafürhalten [ist Herbert seit Dienstag Bischof, wenn nicht Papst.]* (gehobene Ausdrucksweise)
- *Apropos [politisch unkorrekt: Ich sage nicht **Zwerg**, wenn einer klein
  ist, ich sage **Insekt**.]*
- *[Ach,] was ich noch sagen wollte: [Sex ist dreckig.]*
- *Wenn du **mich** fragst[, gibt es auch noch andere Möglichkeiten.]*

Answer (score 5):

Einer Aussage wie *Das ist …* wird ugs. oft eine nicht satzfähige Phrase nachgestellt:

- *… – **meine Meinung!***

Häufig ist das ein [regional gebräuchlicher **Fragepartikel**](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-2/f19a-b/):

- *…, ne?*
- *…, nich(t)?*
- *…, nicht wahr?*
- *…, wa?*
- *…, gell(e)?*
- *…, woll?*
- *…, oder?*
- *…, hmm?*
- *…, stimmt’s?*

Es gibt auch einige längere einschlägige Fragefloskeln:

- *… Hab(e) ich nicht Recht?*
- *… Das wird man doch wohl [noch] sagen dürfen/können?!*

Solche rhetorischen Fragen können auch für die gesamte Aussage verwendet werden:

- *Ist das nicht …?*
- ***Findest du** das [nicht] auch [so] …?* bzw.
  *Findest du [nicht] auch, dass …?*

Auch eine einleitende Interjektion kann die Subjektivität der folgenden Aussage unterstreichen:

- ***Boah**, ist das …!*
- ***Alta**, ist das …!*
- ***Oh**, ist das …!*
- ***Mei**, ist das …!*

Einige eingeschobene Partikeln können eine ähnliche Funktion erfüllen:

- *Das ist **fei** …*
- *Das ist **wohl** …*
- *Das ist **doch** …*
- *Das ist **vermutlich** …*
- *Das ist **wahrscheinlich** …*

Answer (score 2):

Ich werfe noch mal ein paar etwas weiter hergeholte ein:

- Wenn mich nicht alles täuscht, [ist heute nicht mehr Ostermontag]
- Soweit ich weiß, [ist Dienstag]

und sehr indirekt:

- Man könnte meinen, [bald wäre Mittwoch]
- (Es) Sieht fast so aus, als ob [danach Donnerstag käme]

Diese letzten Sätze bedeuten buchstäblich etwas anderes, werden aber mitunter benutzt, um umgangssprachlich eigene Meinungen zu vertreten.